# Bizarre Ruby on Rails Error (AssociationTypeMismatch)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Real problem with an existing webapp which has been working for the last couple of years...

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch (Note(#23706868500220) expected, got String(#23706844996600)):
  app/controllers/jobs_controller.rb:56:in `new'
  app/controllers/jobs_controller.rb:56:in `create'
```

Line 56 of jobs_controller.rb:

```
@jobs = Jobs.new(params[:jobs])
```

Parameters from Console:

```
Parameters: {
  "label" => { "userid" => "332" },
  "jobs"  => {
    "sub"     => "7",
    "notes"   => "Test Note Information",
    "master"  => "1",
    "user_id" => "332",
    "file"    => "Screen shot 2010-02-19 at 13.33.19.png",
    "ref"     => "12345",
    "jobtitle"=> "Test Job",
    "status"  => "0"
  },
  "x"     => "111",
  "y"     => "6",
  "id"    => "newjob"
}
```

Anyone able to advise?

Cheers,

Carl

Comment: Need more info about the Job model, can you post code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem like you have a declaration in your Job model that is causing grief:

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :notes
end
```

When you try and assign to an association like that, you will get conflict. You need to convert the textual note into a proper record before assigning it.

You may be able to do something like this:

```
params[:jobs][:notes] = [ Note.new(:note => params[:jobs][:notes]) ]
```

The actual parameter names will depend on your Note model.

You can also investigate [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/2/1/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-nested-attributes) but that could be a separate question.